# Warming up a drum in storage

Tags: thermodynamics

I need to calculate how long time it will take for a drum filled with a liquid to come to the temperature of the storage room. These are the values that I know:

Surface area of drum: $2.27\, \mathrm m^2$

Weight of liquid & drum: $200\,\mathrm{kg}$

Room temperature: $22\,°\mathrm C$

Approximate heat capacity of the liquid: $1.54\,\mathrm{J\, g^{-1} \, K^{-1}}$

Now I need to calculate how long will it take the drum to heat up to $22\,°\mathrm C$ when it is delivered at a) $-30\, °\mathrm C$ and b) $0 \,°\mathrm C$

I need approximate numbers actually, not exact values. For example, will it take a day, or a week?

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. This is a wonderful site for physics questions and answers, but we have guidelines to keep the quality high. We provide calculations only if the question shows effort on the part of the asker, shows where they're stuck, and asks for help on a particular part of the problem. Generic appeals for calculations are considered off topic under the so-called "homework policy". Please show where you're stuck and then we can help. If the problem is that you don't know how to get started, then ask a more conceptual question, i.e. the numbers are irrelevant.

Comment: Your question needs much more information before anyone can attempt an answer.  How viscous is the liquid?  Is the liquid frozen in the drums when it arrives?  Are a lot of drums packed tightly together in the room?  Is there air circulation in the room, and if so, what is your best guess for the air velocity around the drums?  Are the drums sitting on the floor alone, or are they stacked on top of each other?

Comment: Liquid is not so viscous. We are looking for the worst case scenario so yes, the compound will be frozen when it arrives. If it arrives liquid, there is no problem. Let's solve the case for a single drum, in a well ventilated storage room

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this depends on the thermal properties of the drum and the convectivity coefficient between the drum and air.

Let's assume that the drum is a really good thermal conductor, and that only convection limits the heat transfer. Let's call $h$ the convection coefficient between the drum and air (it depends on the physical characteristics of you device). Then, assuming the system operates under stationnary conditions, the thermal flux through the sides of the drum is

$$ \Phi = hS\theta $$

Where $\theta = T_{ext} - T $

And, $$\frac{\textrm{d}T}{\textrm{d}t} = -\frac{\textrm{d}\theta}{\textrm{d}t} = \frac{\Phi}{c}$$

So $$\frac{\textrm{d}\theta}{\textrm{d}t} = -\frac{hS}{c}\theta$$

which gives $$\theta = \theta_0 \exp(-\frac{t}{\tau})$$

where $\tau = \frac{c}{hS}$. Then, say you want $| \theta |$ to be less than $\theta_{lim}$, then it will take $- \tau \ln(\frac{\theta_{lim}}{\theta_0})$ for the drum to reach this value.

Now, let's find approximatively $h$. We know that $h = \frac{\lambda_{air} \times Nu}{L}$ where $Nu$ is the Nusselt number and $L$ the characteristic length of the drum. I assume that the convection is not forced, so $Nu \approx 2$, and given the surface of the drum, we can assume that $L \approx 50\,cm$. Finaly, $\lambda_{air} = 0.03 \, W\cdot m^{-1}\cdot K^{-1}$. So we have $$\tau \approx \frac{1,540}{2.27 \times \frac{0.03 \times 2}{0.5}} \approx 6000\,s \approx 2\,h$$

Say you want $\theta_{lim} = 2°C$, then if $\theta_0 = 22\,°C$, it will take around $3.8\,h$, while if $\theta_0 = 52\,°C$, it will take around $5.2\,h$

Comment: This has my upvote but has a slight problem; it measures "$\theta$ to be 5% of $\theta_0$" which is why it gets the same answer for both. Realistically you want, say, $\theta_1 = 2^\circ\text{C}$ (or whatever your real tolerance is) whereas $\theta_0$ goes from $22^\circ\text{C}$ to $52^\circ\text{C}.$ So the numbers should be $\tau ~\ln(\theta_1 / \theta_0)$ and it's around 5.1 hours for the $55^\circ\text{C}$ case versus around 3.8 hours for the $22^\circ\text{C}$ case; it of course makes some difference when the thing starts from a cooler temp.

Comment: Your answer smells plausible but perhaps too short to me: based just on the thermal capacity of the liquid, the mass and the temperature change, I reckon you need an average flux of 500W for the 22K change case in 3.8 hours, and 850W for the 52K in 5.2.  That's clearly ball-park right, but I worry it is high.

Comment: Sorry but that short time is not possible, I wish it was. We got 5 kg of the material in a plastic bottle and it took a day to thaw. From 0 to 22 C, let's say.